Proof of countable Borel uniformization
Corollary 13.8 of these notes says that the Borel sets are closed under Borel functions whose fibers are all countable.  Trying to digest that proof, but there's a step I'm unable to follow.  I'll recap the proof and then point to what I'm not getting.
For $f: Z \to X$ Borel function with all fibers countable, between Polish spaces $Z$ and $X$, the proof takes $Z$ to be wlog the product $X \times Y$ (for $Y$ some other Polish space) and $f: X \times Y \to X$ to be $proj_1$ (i.e., projection onto first factor, so $X$ here).  If $B \subseteq X \times Y$ is Borel, the Luzin–Novikov theorem says that $B = \bigcup_n B_n$, where each $B_n$ is a Borel graph. Then define

$k : X → \mathbb{N}$ by $k(x) =$ the least $n ∈ N$ with $x \in proj_1
(B_n)$
$g : X → X \times Y$ by $g(x) = (x, y)$, where $y \in Y$ is unique element with $(x, y) \in B_{k(x)}$.

It is then claimed that $k$ and therefore $g$ are Borel functions.  My question is, why is $k$ a Borel function?  Having a feeling that my confusion may trace back to the "wlog"-maneuver above, but not super sure.  (Also not completely sure why it's ok to assume that $Z$ is such a product and that $f$ is a projection, but anyhow...)
